# Submodels and parent context

Tags: knockout.js

I have isolated my problem in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xYphz/

It uses the root model instead of the parent

edit: 
One obvious solution would be to use templates, but there must be a easier way of getting correct context?

http://jsfiddle.net/eHrBR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you would do something like this:

```
<!-- ko with: subModel -->
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.clickMe">Click me</button>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This ensures that the parent context is your `subModel`.  You can, of course, put the `with` binding on an element rather than use the containerless binding.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xYphz/1/